# За что отвечает ссылка в Debug Extension for Yii 2?

Tags: yii2, ide

Читаю доку и там есть пример:
You can create a link to open files in your favorite IDE with this configuration:

```
return [
    'bootstrap' => ['debug'],
    'modules' => [
        'debug' => [
            'class' => 'yii\debug\Module',
            'traceLine' => '<a href="phpstorm://open?url={file}&line={line}">{file}:{line}</a>', // Эта ссылка
        ],
        // ...
    ],
    ...
];
```

Я что-то не понял из описания что она даст. Панель отладки в PHPStorm что ли появится? Что делать если у меня NetBeans?

Comment: При клике по этой ссылке откроется файл и будет выделена строка, в которой была ошибка. Там просто для примера указан PhpStorm, если NetBeans такое тоже поддерживает, то просто поищите как там формируется ссылка и подставьте туда `{file}` и `{line}`

Comment: @RTK а это типа что бы из веба сразу шторм на нужном месте открыть? Типа как телегам-ссылка в приложении открывается?

Comment: @fosh4451 да, чтоб не самому по файлу глазами искать, а сразу на нужном месте